# Reading from txt file in Java

Tags: java, text, file-io

I wrote this code for reading from txt in Java:

```java
package exe;

import java.io.*;

public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solve g = new Solve(args[0]);
    }
}

class Solve {

    public Solve(String fileName) {

        String line = null;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Reading...");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a txt file named test in the same directory as the `Class1.java` file.I also give `test.txt` as argument in this program so if I print `args[0]` in `Class1`, `test.txt` is printed. I also tried using the full path like this:`Solve("C:\\Users....exe\\src\\test.txt");` but it still produces an exception.

What am I doing wrong?

The txt contains 5 lines on text so I expected `Reading...` to appear 5 times.

Comment: *it still produces an exception*: replace `System.out.println("Exception");`by `ex.printStackTrace()`, and you'll know which exception is thrown, its type, its message, and which line throws it. Ignoring error messages is what makes your life difficult. Or even better, don't catch the exception. Add a throws clause to your methods instead, since you can't handle it in a meaningful way anyway.

Comment: Also, when you execute `ls foo` or `dir foo`, does the `ls` or `dir` program look for the file in the same directory as the `ls` or `dir` executable? Or does it look into the current directory? The same rule applies for Java.

Comment: As an aside: you should not start the computation in the constructor. You should rather move the computation in an instance method.

Comment: Once you have the code working an improvement you could make is to use `try` with resources rather than `try`

Answer (score -1):

Above code is correct and is working fine.

Comment: It should be a comment.